# How to configure Spring Batch to consume non-blocking HTTP resource

Tags: java, spring-batch, nonblocking, jetty-9

I am having trouble understanding how to configure SpringBatch to consume a non-blocking HTTP resource.

In my long running perfectly parallel logic all systems are blocked on the size of the threadpool of my 8-core client application. Neither the client nor the server cluster has any appreciable CPU or memory usage, and on the client all the threads are blocked on a single blocking-HTTP request.

My goal is to replace the blocking-HTTP request with a non-blocking one using Jetty9's non-blocking HttpClient but I don't see how to configure SpringBatch. The data set is large and will likely result in 2-3 million requests per iteration each request will take 200ms to complete. With my ballpark numbers it would take 111 hrs with a single thread naively 14 hrs with eight threads.

Unfortunately, I can not simply drop in the non-blocking HTTP call because SpringBoot would just start executing the next step before sufficient data has been retrieved. Also, I don't want to just expand the threadpool because that just results in more blocked threads.

Does anyone have suggestions or an example with how I should proceed.

Comment: Use Spring 5.0 and Spring Boot 2.0.  They can use non-blocking IO.

Comment: I just edited my question because I meant to ask SpringBatch not SpringBoot. Does this comment still hold true?

Comment: Sorry, not a Spring Batch expert.